# s3_client time out when changing region -- Boto3 Region Credentials

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a boto3 python3 project that just pulls S3 policies down. The issue is it only works in east. I have the code

```
   s3_client = boto3.client('s3',region_name=bucket.region) 
   s3_client.head_bucket(Bucket = bucket.name)
```

But when the region is `us-west-2` If I look in the logs, it makes several http requests that time out and I noticed that the region in the header credentials is always "us-east-1."

EDIT: here are the debug_logs:

```
2021-08-06 13:53:08,319 urllib3.connectionpool [DEBUG] Starting new HTTPS connection (5): [bucket-name].s3.amazonaws.com:443
2021-08-06 13:54:08,416 botocore.endpoint [DEBUG] Exception received when sending HTTP request.
```

And the bottom of the stack is just `The handshake operation timed out`

Comment: what's the question? do you want it to work in for any region? do you have access to all regions? Is your aws IAM policy allowing you to run boto from any region? Can you add these details.

Comment: My role has access to us-west-2 and us-east-1. My question is why do s3_client time out?

Comment: Can you add `s3_client time out when changing region` in your question's title, or at least the body. Can you also post the logs you are looking at! thank you.

Comment: Where is this code running -- is it on your own computer, or an EC2 instance? It sounds a little like it might be running on EC2 without an Internet Gateway, accessing S3 via a VPC Endpoint, which will only allow access to the same region. But, without such details in your question, it is difficult to answer.

Comment: Its running on my own computer. Im running it locally, and there isn't much more context to say. I can't hit buckets in west, despite the role being able to access it in the console.